# Why I am getting parameter is initialized error in C?

Tags: c, parameters, initialization

```
struct subscriber

{

  char phonenumber[20];

  char name[50];

  float amount;

}s;

void modifyrecords()

  FILE *f;

  char phonenumber[20];

  long int size=sizeof(s);

  if((f=fopen("c:/file.ojs","rb+"))==NULL)

    exit(0);

  system("cls");

  printf("Enter phone number of the subscriber to modify:");

  scanf("%[^\n]",phonenumber);

  fflush(stdin);

  while(fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,f)==1)

  {

    if(strcmp(s.phonenumber,phonenumber)==0)

    {

      system("cls");

      printf("\n Enter phone number:");

      scanf("%s",&s.phonenumber);

      printf("\n Enter name: ");

      fflush(stdin);

      scanf("%[^\n]",&s.name);

      printf("\n Enter amount: ");

      scanf("%f",&s.amount);

      fseek(f,-size,SEEK_CUR);

      fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,f);

      break;

    }

  }

  fclose(f);

}
```

C:\Users***\Desktop\a.c|394|error: parameter 'size' is initialized|
I am getting parameter 'size' is initialized error in this code. After googling I found out I may have to pass certain arguments to suppress these kind of errors. Is this the only solution? Actually I am using Code::Blocks so if is the only way how do I pass command line arguments in it?

Comment: It often helps to show the actual text of the error you're getting, along with a minimum *compilable* fragment that produces the error.

Comment: size is not really a parameter, but a variable here. You should get this error from somewhere else.

Comment: At no point in this code is there a *parameter* named 'size'.  You are showing us the wrong piece.  Please construct an example that we can compile for ourselves and get the same results you are getting.

Comment: What kind of compiler do you use or is it a runtime error?

Comment: mingw with code::blocks. Although I just tried it on Ubuntu with gcc and it is still not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a simple syntax error here:

```
void modifyrecords()
```

should be:

```
void modifyrecords() {
```

Also, this:

```
scanf("%s",&s.phonenumber);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s",s.phonenumber);
```

And that applies to `s.name` as well.

Comment: I was going to say that this doesn't explain the error messages, but actually it does!  I totally forgot about K&R-style function parameter declarations.